# How to stub a method that sets an object attribute in a Rails test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocha.js

I'm building a Rails spec test that has a Struct called temp_coverage, like this:

```
  temp_coverage = Struct.new(:paydays) do
    def calculate_costs
      50
    end
  end
```

And in my spec, I call a method using the temp_coverage, but I'm getting an error since the code I am testing is doing the following:

```
temp_coverage.req_subscriber_election_amount = subscriber_election_amount
```

And I am getting an error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `req_subscriber_election_amount=' for < struct paydays=12 >

How can I stub out the setting of an attribute on a struct in my spec?

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this you're looking for?

```
temp_coverage = double('temp_coverage', paydays: nil)

allow(temp_coverage).to receive(:calculate_costs).and_return(50)
allow(temp_coverage).to receive(:req_subscriber_election_amount=) do |argument|
  temp_coverage.instance_variable_set(:@req_subscriber_election_amount, argument)
end

# Example:
temp_coverage.req_subscriber_election_amount = 123
puts temp_coverage.instance_variable_get(:@req_subscriber_election_amount)
# => 123
puts temp_coverage.paydays
# => nil
puts temp_coverage.calculate_costs
# => 50
```

Comment: thanks Jay-Ar, that is exactly what I would like to achieve, but when I run the spec I'm getting an undefined method 'allow'.  Is that a new rspec command?

Comment: oh, I think you're using the old rspec. Is your rspec version >= 3? [Old RSpec Reference](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-99/docs/)

Comment: @MarkKadlec, oh I see. Hmm, might be better to update your "tags" into `mocha`. Not too familiar with mocha, but I can take a look on it later I guess when I have the time.

Comment: I appreciate your input Jay-Ar, looks like the syntax for rspec is there, just need to figure out the syntax for Mocha.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this by using a named Struct.  So once I named my Struct:

```
 temp_coverage = Struct.new('CoverageClass', :paydays) do
    def calculate_costs
      50
    end
  end
```

I could then do the following:

```
Struct::CoverageClass.any_instance.stubs(:req_subscriber_election_amount).returns(25)
```